# Как выбрать запросом данные в коллекцию, каждый элемент которой содержит другую коллекцию?

Tags: sql, oracle, коллекции, plsql

Пытаюсь найти способ массовой выборки в многоуровневый тип данных, т.е. в коллекцию, каждый элемент которой, содержит другую коллекцию. Пример ниже поможет понять то, что пытаюсь сделать.

Есть таблица с денормализованным списком округов и городов:

```
create table county_town (county varchar2(20), town varchar2(20));
insert into county_town values ('Surrey', 'Dorking');
insert into county_town values ('Surrey', 'Woking');
insert into county_town values ('Surrey', 'Guildford');
insert into county_town values ('Oxfordshire', 'Thame');
insert into county_town values ('Oxfordshire', 'Abingdon');
```

Хочу загрузить эту таблицу в многоуровневый тип данных, который выглядит так:

```
create or replace type towns_type force as table of varchar2(20)
/
create or replace type county_type as object (county varchar2(20), towns towns_type)
/
create or replace type counties_type force as table of county_type
/

counties counties_type;
```

Можно ли выбрать с `BULK COLLECT` из таблицы `county_town` данные в `counties`?

Если с `BULK COLLECT` не получится, то есть ли другой простой способ сделать это?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Select into multilevel type in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62697905) от участника [@David Taylor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12216194/david-taylor)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/62697905

Answer (score 2):

На больших таблицах так будет предпочтительней:

```
var rc refcursor
declare 
    counties counties_type;
begin 
    select county_type (county, cast (collect (town) as towns_type)) as counties_type
    bulk collect into counties
    from county_town
    group by county;
    
    open :rc for 
        select * from table (counties);
end;
/
```

Если данных не так много, то можно обойтись без `BULK COLLECT` таким запросом:

```
select cast (multiset (
    select  county_type (county, cast (collect (town) as towns_type)) as counties_type
    from county_town
    group by county
    ) as counties_type) into counties from dual;
```

Результат обоих запросов будет идентичен:

```
COUNTY               TOWNS                                           
-------------------- ------------------------------------------------
Oxfordshire          TOWNS_TYPE('Thame', 'Abingdon')                 
Surrey               TOWNS_TYPE('Dorking', 'Guildford', 'Woking')
```

---

На [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7d4410ba2b284d24c064b7c8e80c38fe).